# overlapping text on the coreplot pie chart

Tags: label, core-plot, pie-chart, overlapping

What is the best way to prevent overlapping text on coreplot? Especially when some of the slices may be quite small? The overlapping text appears at the bottom, I think that it runs out of space to put it anywhere and thus must pile one label on top of the other.

I could reduce the size of the pie chart, but is there a more elegant way of achieving this?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Plot doesn't do anything about overlapping labels right now. You have to use your knowledge of the data and remove some of the labels that might be too close together.